# data.table: How to do binary search for two (numeric) values at one key: example included

Tags: r, data.table

The example data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a = c(1, 3, 5, 9, 15), 
                 b = c("a", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
```

I would like to get two rows which is `a == 3 | a == 9` , that is

```
# a b
# 3 c
# 9 e
```

I know if I do: `DT[, a:=as.character(a)]` then `setkey(DT, a)` and `DT[c("3", "9")]`, I can get the wanted result. But I would like to know, if there are other methods to do this kind of binary search without changing `a` to character in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert it into a character vector (although integer would make more sense)

```
 DT <- data.table(a = c(1, 3, 5, 9, 15), b = c("a", "c", "d", "e", "f"))
 setkey(DT, a)
 DT[J(c(3, 9))]
```

Moreover, if you have the latest version in CRAN, the second time you use a in i will automatically uses binary search

Comment: This is incorrect. This is a normal subset operation of the 3rd and the 9th row. You should do: `DT[J(c(3,9))]`. Automatic indexing is only implemented for `DT[col == .]` and `DT[col %in% .]` at the moment. So, you can do: `DT[a %in% c(3,9)]` without setting the key, and the first time an automatic index will be generated, which'll result in subsequent subsets on `col` faster.

Comment: Thanks Arun. You are right. I would like to know: DT[J(c(3, 9))] and DT[a %in% c(3, 9)], which one is more faster?

Comment: ok. I try to test this using rbenchmark, and do 30000 times replications. The result is that `DT[a %in% c(3,9)]` is a little faster than `DT[J(c(3,9))]`. Thanks Matthew and Arun.

Comment: @BioChemoinformatics, if you tried on this tiny data, it doesn't really mean anything irrespective of how many times you run it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it in the big data.

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't have to convert to a character column every time before to perform a join/binary search based  subset. You can use `J()` and pass an integer / numeric / character / logical / bit64::integer64 vector to it, like so:

```
DT[J(vec1, vec2, ...)]
```

where, `vec1` will be matched against the first key column and `vec2` against the second key column and so on.

The fact that you don't have to add a `J()` for *character* types is an *additional feature*, just for convenience. Because a integer/numeric/logical vector already has a meaning as such - `DT[1]` would return the first row, we can't provide the same shortcut for those types. Hope this answers your original question.

Coming back to your question, to subset column `a` with values `(3,9)`, you can do it using `data.table`'s binary search based subset:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(DT, a)
DT[J(c(3,9))] ## alternatively DT[.(c(3,9))] in 1.9.4+
#    a b
# 1: 3 c
# 2: 9 e
```

There are two things to note, for you to *fast* subset using `data.table`'s binary search feature:

- It requires that you sort your entire data (which may not be always desirable).
- On very large datasets, the time to rearrange the data in memory could be time consuming (finding the order itself is usually much cheaper than moving data around).

---

To address these issues and to provide better functionality, data.table addresses this problem in 1.9.4 by introducing a new *experimental feature* - automatic indexing, with the help of *secondary keys*. Matt has implemented this in 1.9.4.

What automatic indexing does is, if a secondary key doesn't already exist, on the first run of an expression that data.table understands (at the moment) can be optimised, a secondary key will be created. It just stores the order of this column using data.table's fast radix ordering, and stores it as an attribute. There's no reordering of the data at all, unlike `setkey`. You can also set the secondary key using `set2key()`.

The first time you run it, the time taken is equal to a) time for secondary key (usually very small), and b) time for the query. And from second time on, it's just the time to query, and that's fast using binary search.

If you query another column with an expression that data.table understands now, then it'll additionally set a secondary key for that column as well, the first time it's run. And so on...

There should be no (noticeable) differences in speed between the two methods (once `setkey` and `set2key` are done). See example below.

The concept of secondary keys can be extended beyond automatic indexing, to joins as well. This will speedup data.table joins even further.

---

Here's an example. I'll use 1.9.5, as Matt's already fixed some bugs in automatic indexing.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
set.seed(45L)
DT = data.table(x=sample(1e3, 5e7, TRUE))[, y := x]
setkey(DT, x)
set2key(DT, y)
```

Note that after `setkey(.)` `DT` will be reordered, by reference. But `set2key` would just set an attribute, and therefore your data wouldn't be reordered based on y's order.

The columns x and y are identical (on purpose). Let's test both:

```
system.time(DT[J(100L)])   ## on column x, 0.003 seconds
system.time(DT[y == 100L]) ## on column y, 0.003 seconds, uses secondary keys

identical(DT[J(100L)], DT[y==100L]) # [1] TRUE
```

How much time does it take with a vector scan?

```
options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)
system.time(DT[y == 100L]) ## 0.428 seconds
```

Comment: Also, you can also introduce `.(` maybe as in `DT[.(c(3,9))]` maybe, or if the numbers are consecutive, something like `DT[.(3:9)]`